# Не работает функция ConnectNamedPipe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pipes

Очень нужна ваша помощь. Было создано приложение для работы с именованным каналом(код прикреплен). При тестировании выполнялся сначала первый пункт меню, потом второй, и вот при выполнении второго пункта функция ConnectNamedPipe возвращала код ошибки 6(ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE), при чем что странно, сначала при тестировании все работало, но после нескольких запусков перестала работать функция ConnectNamedPipe, функция CreateNamedPipe работает корректно. Перезагружал компьютер, переименовывал канал в коде, создавал новый проект - ничего не помогает. Вообще не знаю что делать, интернет весь перерыл, ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста. В чем может быть проблема?

```
int menu()
{
int choise = 0;
cout << "1 - Create the Pipe" << endl;
cout << "2 - Connect the Pipe" << endl;
cout << "3 - Write to the Pipe" << endl;
cout << "4 - Disconnect the Pipe" << endl;
cout << "0 - Exit" << endl;
cin >> choise;
return choise;
 }

int main() {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
///*

HANDLE hPipe = NULL;
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
overlapped.Offset = 0;
overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
char buffer[512];
int choise = menu();
while (choise != 0) {
    switch (choise)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe1", PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | WRITE_DAC, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 512, 512, 0, NULL);
        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            cout << "Pipe was created\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Can't create the pipe\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        bool connected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);
        if (connected)
        {
            cout << "Connected to the pipe\n";
        }
        else {
            DWORD connectedError = GetLastError();
            cout << connectedError;
        }
        //if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL)) {
        //  cout << "Connected to the pipe\n";
        //}
        //else {
        //  cout << "Can't connect the pipe\n";
        //}
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 0);
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        cin >> buffer;
        WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, NULL, &overlapped);
        WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);
        cout << "Written\n";
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
        CloseHandle(overlapped.hEvent);
    }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    choise = menu();
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: Линукса под рукой нет, но глядя на код, видно , что там, где у вас `HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe()...;` происходит скрытие переменной `hPipe`, во втором кейсе `hPipe` всё ещё `NULL`.
Читайте вывод компилятора - он на это точно ругался. А если бы ещё дебагером прошлись...

Comment: @Genjutsu Да, я продебажил и Вы правы, после CreateNamedPipe она не NULL, но почему-то когда мы заходим во второй кейс, то hPipe имеет значение NULL, только я не понял почему, можете объяснить пожалуйста?

Comment: @Genjutsu, мучаюсь уже несколько дней

Comment: @Genjutsu немного непонятно что значит происходит скрытие hPipe в HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe()?

Comment: @Genjutsu вообщем я написал вместо HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe() просто hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(), получается я два раза одну переменную создавал, но теперь функция ConnectNamedPipe просто зависает и приложение не реагирует, в дебаге hPipe уже не NULL и все равно все зависает( не понятно что делать теперь

Comment: Почитайте про области видимости переменных в c++. В `case 1` у вас другая область видимости, соответственно `HANDLE hPipe` в ней - это уже совсем другая переменная. Если замените объявление на присваивание, должно заработать.

Comment: @Genjutsu да я исправил это(написал в комменте выше), но теперь ConnectNamedPipe просто зависает

Comment: Тут уже я вам ничего не посоветую, кроме как читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-connectnamedpipe).